# Android thinking about the stack

Tags: android

I have a the following scenario:

1. Activity A: A list of items where user can select an item
2. Activity B: A list of options for the selected item
3. Activity C: A shopping cart displaying the selected item and selected options

In Activity C I have a button to allow for continued shopping. It easy to load a new instance of Activity A when the user clicks on continue shopping but if the user adds many items I will have many instances of no longer needed Activities.

My two questions:

- Is there a safe way to get back to activity A? What does the code look like?
- Should I just recreate the Activity each time and trust the OS to kill the previous instances? In other words is there a performance reason to worry about having multiple instances.

Comment: You'll want to take a look at Intent Flags, these flags determine how Activities are handled and stored on the stack, there are a number of flags they are here in the docs, look for ints with names starting with FLAG_ACTIVITY_ http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: So just to be sure I understand: if I set FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP if Activity A is still in the stack it will clear all activities on top of A but if it's not it will launch a new instance.

Comment: That's correct, you start the activity as normal but supply that flag and if the Activity is on the stack the intent will be delivered to the existing instance of the Activity and the method onNewIntent will be invoked.